# Discovery Server - topics fail to recover from network disruption

Tags: network, ros-galactic

Summary:
Multi robot system, experiencing network interruptions between entities of ~30-120s lapses where all or most traffic fails to get through. When the network recovers, inter-robot communication fails to resume. Intra-robot communication uses shared memory and never lapses to begin with.

Setup:

- ROS2 Galactic
- Ubuntu
- FastRTTPS RMW
- ROS Discovery Server
- All messages have the Reliable QoS with volatile durability

Observations:

- When the network health recovers the ROS communications are permanently disrupted. No topics resume flowing along existing discovered connections, and a new super client participant cannot discover any topics from the disrupted robot.
- Topics subscribed to internally between nodes running on the affected robot continue to flow internally.
- Topics subscribed to by other entities in the system are visible with `ros topic list` but no actual messages flow.
- Relaunching the ROS nodes on the impacted robot properly refreshes the connections to the other system entities.
- `ros2 daemon stop/start` on the impacted robot predictably doesn’t fix connection issues
- No ROS or system logs indicating any sort of error.

This leaves 2 open questions:

1. Is there any way we can either force rediscovery or reconnection on the impacted node, or at the very least detect that the messages are no longer flowing on the Robot side?
2. Are there any ways we can further diagnose if this is indeed a discovery problem or something else in the stack?